# HTML launch.json

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML code.
when I program only HTML and CSS code in visual studio code the software automatically creates
launch.json and that stops debugging of my code.

how can I overcome that problem?
thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+launch.js+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: [RTM](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) - what do you meant by "stops debugging" ?